# Hide Fancybox triggered on Page Load on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

Site: beauforgovernor.com

I have a fancybox triggered on page load (only on the homepage), but I don't want it to show up on mobile phones; however, I do still want it to show up on tablets.

I'm not sure how to code this.

This is the JS i'm currently using:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#aLink").fancybox({
        'width'             : '640',
        'height'            : 'auto',
        'autoScale'         : true,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Youll want to choose which screen dimensions you consider as *mobile*, might be hard as some tablet are barely bigger than some smartphone...

```
$(function(){
    var viewport = {
        width  : $(window).width(),
        height : $(window).height()
    };
    if(viewport.width>"480" && viewport.height>"600")
    {
        $("#aLink").fancybox({
            'width'             : '640',
            'height'            : 'auto',
            'autoScale'         : true,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe'
        });
    }
);
```